# Is it possible to list the files between two names alphanumerically?

Tags: shell, command-line, files, ls

Consider a directory with the following files.

```
20160909_154139.jpg
20160909_154038.jpg
20160909_153929.jpg
20160909_153927.jpg
20160908_121201.jpg
20160908_121155.jpg
```

When I do `ls` with no arguments, I get the files in the order above.

Let's say instead I just wanted the files in this order between `20160909_154038.jpg` and `20160908_121201.jpg`.

Is there some argument I can pass to `ls` to specify this desire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can certainly be achieved by piping the output into `awk`

```
ls | awk '/^20160909_154038\.jpg$/,/^20160908_121201\.jpg$/'
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` version:

```
ls 2016090*.jpg | sed -n '/9_154038/,/8_121201/p'
```